# List of variables as shortcodes in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I have a WP website with prices for forms that are updated once a year. The prices for these forms change from time to time. Rather than updating it page by page, could I use a shortcode to echo the prices from an array?

Example:

```
Form 1 = 100
Form 2 = 150
Form 3 = 300
```

Then [price form1] will print $100 and [price form2] will print $150

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Right now, the answer to your question is: "yes, you can use a shortcode to do that". Do you know how to write shortcodes? Did you encounter any problems while writing it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can create a shortcode from any PHP function. There are many ways to slice this, but for a basic overview using PHP, just add something like this to functions.php in your child theme:

```
function displayformvalue100()
{
  echo '$100';
}
add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode_name', 'displayformvalue100');
```

This will create a shortcode called [my_shortcode_name] which will call your function displayformvalue100. Customize from there, and enjoy!